# JDBC not returning same time zone as system

Tags: java

My database is set to default time zone UTC. My Driver should be using system time which I am running my application in a ubuntu container that is set to UTC. I know this because when I call Timezone.getDefault() is returns UTC. So according to my understanding, these times should be close to identical +-1 hour. I am currently in CST. The database time is retrieved with resultset.getTimestamp().getTime(). One (or two) of these numbers are not UTC.

```
Database time: 1674680930000
System.currentTime(): 1674703050253
Calendar time: 1674703050255
```

Comment: I know that when using MySQL with JDBC, it will convert the incoming timestamp to the DB server timezone and vice-versa when returning it.

Comment: Show your code. [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What database? What driver?

Comment: FYI, you are using terrible date-time classes that were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Comment: @BasilBourque I am using MySql Driver, to connect to my MySql DB.

Comment: @BasilBourque I'm not actually using any date-time classes in my code besides the ones provided by the sql package. The classes I used above 'Timezone'  are just to display a time for testing purposes like finding out what timezone my application is using, which is UTC.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen So I know that my server is currently configured to UTC, that I know for a fact. I was under the impression that my DB was also using UTC, although checking both the global and local timezones indicated that it was using the system timezone which is obviously wrong. So I changed the session timezone to use an offset of 0 (which is UTC i believe). I get the following results. : Database time: 1674724690000; System.currentTime(): 1674746686344. these should be almost identical, but obviously, they are now. My global.timezone is using system timezone.

Comment: So it looks like I missed an important distinction between session and global env variables in MySQL: "Values for TIMESTAMP columns are converted from the session time zone to UTC for storage, and from UTC to the session time zone for retrieval." So session isn't referring to and JDBC connection, but rather just whoever is connected to the DB. So, instead of setting the session timezone to UTC, I would set the global timezone to UTC and reset the session timezone back to default behavior (for preference). This is the solution, my application now retrieves the correct timezone.

Comment: Post needed facts as edits to your Question, not as Comments.

Answer (score 1):

> My database is set to default time zone UTC.

Write your Java code in such a way that you don’t care about the current default time zone of the server OS nor the current default time zone of the database session.

Edit your Question to provide actual example code. Then we can critique.

> My Driver should be using system time which I am running my application in a ubuntu container that is set to UTC.

No, incorrect. Your [JDBC driver](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) is unaware of the host OS’ current default time zone.

What makes you think otherwise? Edit your Question to provide details.

> I know this because when I call Timezone.getDefault() is returns UTC.

That code gets the current default time zone of your [JVM](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine). Your JVM’s current default time zone may or may not be the same as host OS’ the current default time zone. The two defaults can be set independently of one another.

`TimeZone` is one of the legacy date-time classes that you should avoid. Use only *java.time* classes. Never use `Dote`, `Calendar`, `Timestamp`, etc.

To determine your JVM’s current default time zone:

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;
```

> I am currently in CST.

As I said above, you should write your Java code to avoid depending on any default time zone. Pass optional parameters with your desired/expected time zone.

Record the current moment as seen in UTC.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.now( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , odt ) ;
```

Retrieve from database.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
```

Adjust to your desired time zone. `CST` is not a [real time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones). Perhaps you meant `America/Chicago`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Chicago" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = odt.atZoneSameInstant( z ) ;
```

> The database time is retrieved with resultset.getTimestamp().getTime().

Incorrect. The [`ResultSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/ResultSet.html) class has no `getTimestamp` method taking no arguments.

Perhaps you mean to retrieve a date-time value from a column. How to do that depends on the data type of the column.

Edit your Question to document the *exact* data type of your column, the database engine, and the version.

For [MySQL 8](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html):

| SQL standard | MySQL | Java |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` | `TIMESTAMP` | [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) |
| `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE` | `DATETIME` | `LocalDateTime` |

And **search Stack Overflow** to learn more. Exchanging date-time values with a database has been covered extensively.

You commented:

> So it looks like I missed an important distinction between session and global env variables in MySQL:

Neither of those need be relevant to your Java code for exchanging date-time values with a database.

Comment: Well by default ubuntu is using UTC so without any configuration my API is also using UTC because that is what the system is using. The problem was that my DB was using the system timezone, through the global timezone variable, which I changed to default as UTC to match my API. I am running my own copy of the DB on my local computer which was a problem because my system timezone was different and therefore I was getting unexpected results comparing times from the DB in my API.